# Incremental(?) or offset(?) formula EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I need help with something. I have a list of values (in `sheet 2`) and I want to create two rows (where `A4 = A3`) of said values in sheet 1. (Shown below) Is there a formula I can use in Excel that can allow me to copy that formula in sheet one across hundreds of rows?

[image: Example]

Comment: Will the values in Sheet 1 always come in pairs?

Comment: i want to populate two rows on sheet one based on one cell from sheet 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid the volaitle INDIRECT you can use INDEX:

```
=INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/2)+2)
```

Where the `+2` is the starting row of the data on Sheet1.  I assumed row 2, if different change to the actual first row of data.

Comment: So much more clever than my answer

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data in sheet 1 is in column `A`

in Sheet 2, `A1`, add the following formula:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & ROW()*2)
```

And in `B1` add this one:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A" & ROW()*2-1)
```

Then populate down

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this, I just dislike the unnecessary re-calc of multiple formula if it can be avoided.